# Script to label emails if it contains specific words in the subject or body on Gmail

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, gmail

Update:
Thank you so much endothermic_dragon! You are brilliant! It all works now.

I have created scripts before but never for Gmail. I am having a hard time creating a script to filter emails coming in and label and archive them if they have specific words. We receive about 100 emails daily from various senders relating to a group of companies. Each company has its label. Usually the name of the company is in the subject or body of the email. I am trying to build a script that gets each email, check if the array with subjects or the array with plainBody contains the name of one or more of the labels (each label is the name of a company) in the labels array from getUserLabels(), and if so, assign the respective label(s) to it. I have tried everything, from filter() to forEach() to indexOf() but nothing seems to work. I feel the arrays from getUserLabels() and getInoboxThreads() are 2D, and I'm struggling to work with them. I've rewritten the code multiple times and it got me nowhere. I really hope one of you can shed some light on this.

Example:
Let's suppose we work with Apple, Amazon and Netflix. Each of these companies have their own label.
If an email comes in and has "Apple" in the subject or body, then add label "Apple" to it and archive it. If it has "Amazon" and "Netflix" in the subject or body, then add labels Amazon and Netflix.

Final code:

```
function labelEmails() {
  var labels=[]
  GmailApp.getUserLabels().forEach(function(label){labels.push(label.getName())})
  var threads = GmailApp.search('is:unread').forEach(function(email){
    email.getMessages().forEach(function(thread){
      //Filter - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message
      //Example used - if body contains 'hi', mark as read.
      labels.forEach(function(label){
        if (thread.getBody().toLowerCase().includes(label.toLowerCase())){
          labelToAssign = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label);
          labelToAssign.addToThread(email)
        } else if (thread.getSubject().toLowerCase().includes(label.toLowerCase())) { 
           labelToAssign = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label);
          labelToAssign.addToThread(email)
          } 
      })
    })
    });
}
```

Some of our labels are abbreviations of the name of the companies, so I also needed a function to handle those. You can check it out below too:
(Companies in the code are random companies, not the real ones)

```
function labelExceptions() {
  var exceptions = [{exc:'apple', labeln: 'APPL'}, {exc: 'amazon', labeln: 'AMZ'}, {exc: 'Bank of America', labeln: 'BOFA'}]
  var threads = GmailApp.search('is:unread').forEach(function (thread){
    thread.getMessages().forEach(function(message){
      exceptions.forEach(function(exception){
        if (message.getBody().toLowerCase().includes(exception.exc)){
          labeltoAssign = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(exception.labeln);
          labeltoAssign.addToThread(thread)
        } else if (message.getSubject().toLowerCase().includes(exception.exc)){
          labeltoAssign = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(exception.labeln);
          labeltoAssign.addToThread(thread)
        }
      
      })
    
    })}
 );
  }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you share your current code, please? It would be easier to help you out that way.

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon I have written my code over and over and I feel I'm in the wrong direction. I didn't share it because I think it will confuse you about what my goal is.

Comment: You don’t have to wonder about what sort of object is returned when you use a method like get inbox threads just look in the documentation it tells you whats returned. you can go to that class page and see all of the methods and use them to get the information you want it’s not that complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checked with my gmail, works!

```
function myFunction() {
  var labels=[]
  GmailApp.getUserLabels().forEach(function(label){labels.push(label.getName())})
  var threads = GmailApp.search('is:unread').forEach(function(email){
    email.getMessages().forEach(function(thread){
      //Filter - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message
      //Example used - if body contains 'hi', mark as read.
      labels.forEach(function(label){
        if (thread.getBody().toLowerCase().includes(label.toLowerCase())){
          email.markRead()
        }
      })
    })
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Endothemic_Dragon, your suggestion worked really well. I'm just trying to get the code to compare against all labels. For some reason it is not working. Would you mind taking a look? The code is updated in my question.

Comment: It runs but does nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by 'compare against all labels'?

Comment: When an email comes in, I do not know which company it is about. Each label is the name of a company. I need it to check which one is it about and assign the respective label.

Comment: Update - edited to make the comparison case insensitive.

Comment: you are a genius! It works perfectly now! If it hasn't already, I am sure this impressively smart brain of yours will get you very rich!

Comment: @VictorFirmino You should consider **accepting** the answer then

Comment: @Tibebes M Thank you for letting me know. I am new here and did not know about that.